# JS/jQuery Call function from dynamically loaded JS file?

Tags: jquery, dynamic, global-variables

I'm having issues with calling functions from within dynamically loaded JS files.

The setup: I have a main JavaScript "framework", which handles dynamic page calling with HTML5 history, globally required functions, etc. All active links when pressed are handled by my function instead of having the page load. In my main JavaScript file I have a function let's say `foo()` that I'm trying to use in my dynamic JavaScript file.

Currently the way the dynamic pages are setup, is that at the end of the files in the HTML there are lines of specific JavaScript files needed to run that page with just

`<script type="text/javascript">file.js</script>`

They load up and work, however if I call the `foo()` function from within that `files.js` - it returns as not defined.

How do I get the dynamically loaded JavaScript files to "see" the functions I have written in my global JavaScript file?

Thanks

Edit:

Defined in global.js, that is included in the `<head>`:

```
function foo() {
    alert('bar');
}
```

Then,

```
$.get('dynamicPage.html', function(html) {
    $('#content').html(html);
}
```

With the source:

```
<p>This is my dynamic page</p>
<script type="text/javascript">foo();</script>
```

The foo(); function call returns as undefined

Comment: Are those functions global? For example is `window.foo` defined? If you have enclosed your function in a `$(function() {...})` then outside of this scope they are not available.

Comment: Please show concrete examples of what you're doing, it's hard to figure out what could be wrong from your description.

Comment: No, they are just defined as `function foo() { .. }`.

Comment: As long as you define the functions before you call them, you shouldn't get any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `getScript()` function. Could you could load your js files after page load?
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Comment: Is there a way to remove the script after it's added? Currently the included JavaScript files get "discarded" when content is replaced, thus removing them, which is a self working garbage cleaner in a way.

Comment: did you find an answer to this problem? If so could you share?

Answer (score 0):

Try encapsulating in a document ready statement.

$(document).ready(function () { foo(); });

Comment: My global file is encapsulated, I tried doing the same with the dynamic file, still the same..